# Возврат json из wcf сервиса

Tags: c#, json, ajax, wcf

Создаю wcf service application в vs2010 и столкнулся с такой проблемой:запускаю проект на выполнение из vs и при отправке ajax запроса на сервис в консоле браузера выводится сообщение "Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленого ресурса. Это может быть исправлено путем перемещения ресурса в тот же домен или включением cors". Хотя если вводить адресс службы в адресной строке браузера- все корректно работает. Почему так и как решить данную проблему. Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте. Изучите вначале [это](http://javascript.ru/ajax/cross-domain-scripting).
Запуская проект в visual studio, Вы его запускаете на localhost. А сервис на домене. Политика кросс-домена запрещает обращаться из разных доменов к какой либо части сайта.

Для разрешения данного запрета:

1. [Первая ссылка](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspx)
2. [Вторая
       ссылка](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/wcf/X8QN260412-Calling-Cross-Domain-WCF-Service-using-Jquery.html)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, решил проблему.